# How to add DATETIME()

Tags: sql

I have a table consisting of 1 column which has 10 rows of DATETIME()

```
0:2:32
3:6:18
....
....
```

How do I add these to get 
3:8:50?

Comment: What is your rdbms? Do you store date and time or just time? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: After voting to close because the question is unclear, I have a question for you.  What do those numbers represent?

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you only have time on that field. Otherwise you ahve to extract the `TIME` from `DATE` first

```
 SELECT SUM(datefieldname)
 FROM YourTable
```